# Edward Baines in a coma, seals and sailing?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-cell

In The Cell (2000), what is the connection between Edward Baines being in a coma, the seals being killed on the beach as mentioned in the newspaper article, and sailing the boat?

Comment: I'm not sure what the seals have to do with anything. I believe the idea was to get the toy boat sailing in Edward's brain because it represented a happier time for him. Perhaps it would bring him back from the coma.